# AngularJS access further details by matching ids

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This must be simple and Angular probably has an inbuilt directive to do this but I cant think of how to do without looping through the Array.

I have a array of options i.e.

```
$scope.colors=[
  {id:"0",label:"blue"},
  {id:"1",label:"red"},
  {id:"2",label:"green"}
]
```

And then my data object that stores the id of a color option i.e.

```
$scope.data={
  color:"1",
  otherproperty:""
}
```

But when I display the data to the user I want to show the label rather than the id, so is there a easy(angular) way to do this?:

```
{{data.color.label}}
```

Comment: it would be nice to put some html codes. or a fiddle of what have you done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Angular way would be using ng-repeat & filter, your still essentially looping over the Array but all options would require some sort of loop i.e.

```
<div ng-repeat="color in colors | filter:{ 'id':  data.color}:true">
  {{ color.label }}
</div>
```

Setting the Filter strict comparison to 'true' as above will only select the id with an exact match

https://jsfiddle.net/sjmcpherso/wztunyr5/

Comment: I feel this is a perfect answer

Comment: I didn't think to use ng-repeat, Im going to go with this option thanx

Answer (score 0):

The following will return the object where the id matches `$scope.data.color`:

```
var pickedColor = $scope.colors.filter(function( obj ) {
  return obj.id === $scope.data.color;
});
```

`pickedColor.label` will be the label string.

Comment: I'm not sure how I would go about implementing this in my code?

Answer (score 0):

Look at other way, hope it will help you.

https://jsfiddle.net/kkdvvkxk/.

We can also use `$filter` under controller.

Controller :

```
 var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope, $filter) {
  $scope.colors = [{ 
    id: "0",
    label: "blue"
  }, {
    id: "1",
    label: "red"
  }, {
    id: "2",
    label: "green"
  }]
  $scope.data = {
    color: "1",
    otherproperty: ""
  }

  $scope.getLabel = function(colorId) {
    return $filter('filter')($scope.colors, { id: colorId }[0].label;
  }

}
```

HTML :

```
{{ getLabel(data.color)}}
```